# Why Cortex-M requires its first word as initial stack pointer?

Tags: arm, cortex-m

Imagine that I am writing an assembly language program which doesn't use the stack at all.

Why does Cortex-M mandates for a stack pointer ? What does the CPU do with this stack pointer even if I don't use it(Does the CPU require the SP to function ? I don't think that SP is mandatory for a CPU to function.) ?

I makes sense for me to place at the first address the first instruction to be executed or an address where the program begins.

Comment: You might conceivably manage to write a program that doesn't use the stack, but any interrupt or other exception requires it in order to save context.  If you want to live dangerously you can try pointing that value at something that isn't valid RAM, but it's not, shall we say, recommended.

Comment: You are being silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU does not technically require the stack pointer to run. It does, however, require the stack pointer in order to properly service interrupts and exceptions. It places certain information on the stack before servicing an interrupt so that system state can be resumed following the interrupt. You could theoretically experience an exception in the first instruction after boot, so the SP needs to be set up before it begins execution.

In addition, are you familiar with the vector table? Generally the first several addresses in a processor are reserved for the vector table anyway. The vector table contains jump addresses which the hardware references when servicing interrupts and exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You are more than welcome to make your own chips with your own processor, you are also welcome to license ARMs products and perhaps modify them.

The cortex-m vs full sized arm makes a whole lot of sense.  arm made the effort in this design to make it such that you dont have to have any assembly language or at least not as much.  two things that a bootstrap has to do to get you from first instruction of an event handler (reset is an event) to C functions to handle that event.  One is the stack, second is preserve state (save registers that have to be preserved before entering the next layer function on the stack ideally).  They do both of these in hardware now.  The initial stack pointer is most definitely not required, but that address cannot be repurposed, if you dont want to put a stack address there, then dont, but whatever you put there will get loaded into r13, that is how the hardware works, dont like it find another processor.  second unlike the full sized arms the vectors are now vectors and not instructions so they are an address so you cant just put your instructions at address 0x4.  Now if you want to get anal about this you can probably put your first instruction at address 0x000 so long as the 32 bit value at address 0x4 is all zeros.  so like a full sized arm the first 32 bits has to be a jump in that case.

The more sane thing to do of course is to reserve a little room for the vector table, maybe your assembly actually wants to service some interrupts (well maybe not you need a stack for that since the hardware is going to use the stack pointer to write to whether you like it or not, find another processor if you dont like it).  then after this reserved space then put your first instrucitons assembly, machine code, whatever and have the reset vector point to this address just like most other processors families.  most have a vector table somewhere not always at address zero, but somewhere and that points to some other place where the code is.

You can do this in as little as 8 bytes in front of your program

```
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

.word   0
.word   _start

.thumb_func
.globl _start
_start:
/* code starts here*/
```

or I am willing to bet this will work too and only cost you 4 bytes not 8. (well technically it costs you 4 or 6 bytes or 8 depending on how you are counting).

```
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb
.thumb_func
.globl _start
_start:
    b over
.word _start
over:
/* code continues here*/
```

so long as the branch definitely generates two 16 bit instructions.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   e001        b.n 6 <over>
   2:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

00000006 <over>:
   6:   e7fe        b.n 6 <over>
```

Nope, didnt work, how about

```
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb
.thumb_func
.globl _start
_start:
    b over
.align
.word _start
over:
/* code continues here*/
    b .
```

ahh, much better.

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   e002        b.n 8 <over>
   2:   bf00        nop
   4:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1

00000008 <over>:
   8:   e7fe        b.n 8 <over>
   a:   bf00        nop
```

If you end up actually wanting to do enough assembly to do something useful then you probably will want the stack and they save you some number of bytes by letting you just load the stack pointer on reset rather have to write code to do it in the reset handler.

assembly means you can do whatever you want, it seems quite obvious here though they were catering to the masses (C) to make their lives just a little bit easier, one stack, most of the time you can now just put the address to your C handler function directly, bootstrap can go away.  things you couldnt do with the full sized and prior arm solutions.

Comment: specifically answering your questions.  No you are generally not required to have a stack or stack pointer to have some code run.  Eventually you want one for a relatively good sized project and to maintain sanity.  Second on this chip so long as you dont have events other than reset you dont need the stack pointer initialized.  Lastly, what makes the most sense to do with any processor is just have your code start where the processor was designed for your code to start which is not necessarily at the first memory location.  or at least not to start where it was not designed to start.

Answer (score -1):

The Stack pointer itself is not needed by the CPU to work, however if we take the same topology then no need to any cpu registers or feature to get the cpu working right? , the point is the CPU itself including all its features is there to serve program flow execution, therefore the stack pointer used mainly by program pointer as a way to backup/restore cpu registers values at entry/exit of each function to keep track of cpu state during program execution.

the Stack pointer serve to backup/restore cpu state during interrupt context switching routine as well, and by tat we make serving interrupts possible , plus we can use the generated stack frame during fault exception entry as a way to analyze the root cause of the fault.

As you can see above , the stack pointer is needed everywhere to get your program execute properly.

The stack pointer in cortex-m occupy the first word of the vector table, vector table is the vector that contain entry handlers to all exception/interrupts in cortex-m, on top of those functions handler addresses it contains as well the stack pointer as first word and address of reset handler as second word.

why the stack pointer chosen to be in the vector table this is due to cortex-m booting routine where the first it start by is fetching the vector table for stack pointer and reset handler, and as cortex-m start right a way with first instruction in reset handler it may need to use stack area as soon a possible if reset handler routine need it, on top of that managing the initialization of stack pointer by hardware speed up the boot routine by itself which is critical for real time based applications.